# Vue Component props as key for object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I do not know how to explain this so here is the code:

Component:

```
Vue.component( 'dropdown', {
    props: [ 'key', ],
    template: `
    <select>
        <option value="0">Please select</option>
        <option v-for="option in fields[key].options" :value="option.value">
            {{ option.text }}
        </option>
    </select>`,
})
```

`fields` is just a global object:

```
var fields = {
    gender: {
        title: 'Select Gender',
        options: [
            {value: 'male', text:'male'},
            {value: 'female', text:'female'}
        ]
    },
    ...
}
```

Finally in my html i have:

```
<dropdown key='gender'></dropdown>
```

In the component I tried to replace `fields[ key ].options` with `fields[ + "'" + key + "'" + ].options` then i got `option is not defined`.
 So after the changes my component

```
Vue.component( 'dropdown', {
    props: [ 'key', ],
    template: `
    <select>
        <option value="0">Please select</option>
        <option v-for="option in fields[ + '\'' + key + '\'' + ].options" :value="option.value">
            static text instead of option.text for tesing
        </option>
    </select>`,
})
```

And now the rendered html is: `<!---->`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that `key` is used by something in Vue or somewhere else and changing it another name like `somekey` solved the problem.

For those who may need this in the future, here is the new component:

```
Vue.component( 'dropdown', {
    props: [ 'somekey', ],
    template: `
    <select>
        <option value="0">Please select</option>
        <option v-for="option in fields[ somekey ].options" :value="option.value">
            {{ option.text }}
        </option>
    </select>`,
})
```

and of course the in html becomes `<dropdown somekey='gender'></dropdown>`